# I can not link my html pages with the external sheet CSS

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

```css
body{
  background-color: black;
  margin-top: 45px;
}

.backdrop {
  background: url(../images/header.JPG) center;
  background-size: contain;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 185px;
  width: 85vw;
}
   
.text {
  text-shadow: 0 0 9px white;
  color: white;
  border: 4px solid;
  background: rgb(59, 2, 6);
  mix-blend-mode:multiply;
  font: bolder 10vw 'arial';
  text-align: center;
  margin:0;
  animation: glow 3s infinite;
}

@keyframes glow {
  0% {
    text-shadow: 0 0 10px white;
  }
  15% {
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 10px rgba(255, 255, 255, 1),
                 -2px -2px 10px rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  }
  30% {
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 4px rgba(255, 255, 255, .7),
                 -2px -2px 4px rgba(255, 255, 255, .7);
  }
}
    
ul li {
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
  margin-right: 1em; 
}
 
li a {
  color: #544738;
  text-decoration: none;
  float: left;
  font-size: 25px;
  padding: 10px;
  padding-top: 30px;
  margin-left: 155px;
}
 
li a:hover {
  color: #740001;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<title>About me</title>
<link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>


<body>  
    
<h1>About me</h1>
   
    
</body>


</html>

----------------------------------------------------------------
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<title>About me</title>
<link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
    
<h1>Major</h1>
    
    </body>




</html>

--------------------------------------------------------
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<title>About me</title>
<link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body class="gallery">
    
<h1>Gallery</h1>
    
</body>




</html>
-------------------------------------------------
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<title>About me</title>
<link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body class="contact">
    
<h1>contact</h1>
    
</body>




</html>
```

I am creating a website for school... but I haven't been able to link the different HTML pages to the css (for changing the background color etc...)I have 4 HTML pages, I don't know if I have to add divs or something like that, could you please help me to link those html with the main css ? .. I'm going to post the css page, and the three html pages. thank you so much, I would be so glad if you can help me with that.

Comment: Check my updated answer. I think you haven't added the class to your heading.

Answer (score 0):

You need to link your CSS style sheets to each page, in your case you will need to upload your CSS files to your server and reference them.

Convention dictates that they are added in the `<head>`, i.e:

```
<head>

    <link href="PATH_TO_CSS_FILE.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>


<body>

    ... page HTML ...

</body>
```

The snippet you have provided works as it should, the only CSS style that you have in your demonstration HTML (which I imagine is a condensed example) is the `body` tag.

If the CSS styles are not being applied to your working HTML pages then it is likely that you have not correctly linked the CSS stylesheet. You can check the console within your browser to see if there are any errors (i.e. if the stylesheet is not being loaded).

If you wanted your headings (`h1`) to use the effects you've dictated in `.text`, then you need to add the class to the element, i.e.:

```
<h1 class="text">About Me</h1>
```

I have shown a working snippet below.

```css
body{
  background-color: black;
  margin-top: 45px;
}

.backdrop {
  background: url(../images/header.JPG) center;
  background-size: contain;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 185px;
  width: 85vw;
}
   
.text {
  text-shadow: 0 0 9px white;
  color: white;
  border: 4px solid;
  background: rgb(59, 2, 6);
  mix-blend-mode:multiply;
  font: bolder 10vw 'arial';
  text-align: center;
  margin:0;
  animation: glow 3s infinite;
}

@keyframes glow {
  0% {
    text-shadow: 0 0 10px white;
  }
  15% {
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 10px rgba(255, 255, 255, 1),
                 -2px -2px 10px rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  }
  30% {
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 4px rgba(255, 255, 255, .7),
                 -2px -2px 4px rgba(255, 255, 255, .7);
  }
}
    
ul li {
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
  margin-right: 1em; 
}
 
li a {
  color: #544738;
  text-decoration: none;
  float: left;
  font-size: 25px;
  padding: 10px;
  padding-top: 30px;
  margin-left: 155px;
}
 
li a:hover {
  color: #740001;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<title>About me</title>
<link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>


<body>  
    
<h1 class="text">About me</h1>
   
    
</body>


</html>
```

Classes must be applied to each element in order for the styles to take effect. If you want all headings to have the glow effect, etc that you have coded then you may want to think about changing `.text` to `h1` in your stylesheet, so that you do not need to apply the class each time you create a header. For example:

```css
body{
  background-color: black;
  margin-top: 45px;
}

.backdrop {
  background: url(../images/header.JPG) center;
  background-size: contain;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 185px;
  width: 85vw;
}
   
h1 {
  text-shadow: 0 0 9px white;
  color: white;
  border: 4px solid;
  background: rgb(59, 2, 6);
  mix-blend-mode:multiply;
  font: bolder 10vw 'arial';
  text-align: center;
  margin:0;
  animation: glow 3s infinite;
}

@keyframes glow {
  0% {
    text-shadow: 0 0 10px white;
  }
  15% {
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 10px rgba(255, 255, 255, 1),
                 -2px -2px 10px rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  }
  30% {
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 4px rgba(255, 255, 255, .7),
                 -2px -2px 4px rgba(255, 255, 255, .7);
  }
}
    
ul li {
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
  margin-right: 1em; 
}
 
li a {
  color: #544738;
  text-decoration: none;
  float: left;
  font-size: 25px;
  padding: 10px;
  padding-top: 30px;
  margin-left: 155px;
}
 
li a:hover {
  color: #740001;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<title>About me</title>
<link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>


<body>  
    
<h1>About me</h1>
   
    
</body>


</html>
```

Comment: Not sure why you got the down vote but I agree that the dot notation indicates that you are referring to an element class. Seeing that he did not a class in his elements I gave up vote, even though his body background color should be black with a top margin of 45px.

Answer (score 0):

your css is working but you have set the body background color to black and your text is also black

try replacing your first css rule with

```
body{
background-color: white;
margin-top: 45px;
}
```